# How to copy iTunes music from iTunes library to another, using my own music - not purchased

Tags: itunes, windows, music, pc

I have digitised my CD collection and have it on my iTunes on a PC. How can I add it to my partner's iTunes on a different PC?

Comment: You can copy it to a USB flash drive and import it back into iTunes, or re-rip the CDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Send your partner the music files online (such as email)
2. Burn the files to a CD and transfer it to the other computer
3. Copy it to a thumb-drive and transfer it to the other computer

iTunes should automatically open the music files. If it does not, (I'm assuming your PC is a Windows PC) [right click the file, select 'Choose default program', and then choose iTunes in the list.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7) After opening the file in iTunes, it should automatically add it to your partner's iTunes library.